# Array Value on Database PDO(PHP)

Tags: php, html

I have a weird value when I am trying to edit the file/image content when I'm refreshing my database to take a look it has this value

[SAMPLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDZjh.jpg)

Here's my code for editing the content

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-update'])){


    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];


    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"uploaded_files/uploaded_files_articles_images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_fname"],"uploaded_files/uploaded_files_articles/" . $_FILES["files"]["fname"]);


    $location = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $location1 = $_FILES['files']['fname'];


    $sql = "UPDATE article SET title=:title, content=:content, image=:images, file=:files WHERE id=:id";

    $query = $db_con->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':content', $content, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':images', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':files', $location1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();

    header("Location: edit-index.php");
}
```

What could be the problem . I've searched to internet but there's nothing like this.

Comment: If you're referring to array, it's because you must have tried to bind an array as a string in your bindParam statements.  An array can't be converted to a string.

Comment: Owww i see wait

Comment: tried to remove `PDO::PARAM_STR` but still the same

Comment: Well, that wasn't the issue.  The issue is the value is an array.  You can't pass an array to a database column.

Comment: I don't know why the value is `Array` . Hmmm how could I edit the image or file content .

Comment: Why don't you debug?  Use a debugger or use var_dump to see what the values you are passing to the database are....

Comment: @Devon Okay wait

Comment: @Devon try to put `var_dump()` C:\wamp64\www\Cmc\edit.php:36:string 'Chrysanthemum.jpg' (length=17)
C:\wamp64\www\Cmc\edit.php:37:null

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance trying to upload multiple files under the same key? In that case `$_FILES['xxx']['name']` etc will be arrays. You'll have to loop through them and deal with each one individually.

This is where some crude `var_dump()`/`print_r()` debugging might help. ;)

Comment: no actually there's already a file there and I'm trying to edit it . It's only 1 file at a time

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Devon

I solved my problem

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-update'])){


    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];


    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"uploaded_files/uploaded_files_articles_images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_fname"],"uploaded_files/uploaded_files_articles/" . $_FILES["files"]["name"]);


    $location = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $location1 = $_FILES['files']['name'];

    var_dump($location);
    var_dump($location1);


    $sql = "UPDATE article SET title=:title, content=:content, image=:images, file=:files WHERE id=:id";

    $query = $db_con->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':content', $content, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':images', $location);
    $query->bindParam(':files', $location1);
    $query->execute();

    header("Location: edit-index.php");
}
```

The problem was this line

```
$location1 = $_FILES['files']['fname'];
```

Changed it to this

```
$location1 = $_FILES['files']['name'];
```